# How to balance the reaction equation of potassium permanganate, calcium oxalate, and sulfuric acid step by step?

Tags: redox, stoichiometry

I have been desperately trying to balance the following equation, and finally (ultima ratio) used an [online program](http://en.intl.chemicalaid.com/tools/equationbalancer.php?equation=CaC2O4%20%2B%20KMnO4%20%2B%20H2SO4%20%3D%20CaSO4%20%2B%20K2SO4%20%2B%20MnSO4%20%2B%20H2O%20%2B%20CO2) to get it done ([posted the same question there as well](http://forums.chemicalaid.com/topic/5/step-to-step-instruction-on-balancing-given-equation)).
$$\ce{KMnO4 + CaC2O4 + H2SO4 -> MnSO4 + K2SO4 + CaSO4 + CO2 + H2O}\tag{I}$$

No worries, balancing the K, Mn, Ca, C and S - but by then the H and O got out of my control. So this is how far I got myself:
$$\begin{multline}\ce{2KMnO4 + CaC2O4 + 4H2SO4 ->\\
 2MnSO4 + K2SO4 + CaSO4 + 2CO2 + 4H2O}\tag{II}\end{multline}$$

So the only thing left to be balanced, was the O, having 28 on the reagents' side and 24 on the product side. I started off, getting up to 36:33 O (reagents:products), and I felt that I was getting nowhere.

Anyone who would guide me through the steps following the balancing until equation II above?

Comment: You should balance this like any other redox: identify the oxidant, look how many electrons it requires, identify the reducing agent, look...

Answer (score 4):

This is a redox reaction. While it can be balanced by the method you describe, it is much more reliable to balance it by the half-reaction method.

> Step 1 - Identify your spectator ions (so we do not spend time trying to balance them)

Three ions appear unchanged on both sides of the reaction: $\ce{K+},\ \ce{Ca^2+},\ \& \ \ce{SO4^2-}$

> Step 2 - Identify your redox pairs.

You have one manganese species on each side. They must constitute one half-reaction:

$$\ce{MnO4- -> Mn^2+}$$

Likewise, you have on carbon species on each side. They must constitute the other half reaction:

$$\ce{C2O4^2- -> CO2}$$

For each half reaction:

> Step 3 - Balance O by adding $\ce{H2O}$
>
> Step 4 - Balance H by adding $\ce{H+}$
>
> Step 5 - Balance charge by adding $\ce{e-}$
>
> Step 6 - Combine the half reactions

Can you take it from here?